# TypeError Cannot read property 'country_code' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm using React to render a table based on an API call that returns JSON data.

I'm getting a `TypeError` because it cannot read the location object and I cannot figure out why.

I've listed the error, code, and JSON output below.  All other fields render successfully.

**Error**

```
TypeError Cannot read property 'country_code' of null

<td>{host.ip_addresses[0].location.country_code}</td>
```

**Code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";

const ResultTableNew = () => {
  const [hosts, setHosts] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://localhost/domain/example.com/hosts")
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        setHosts(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Table variant="dark" responsive striped hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Hostname</th>
            <th>IPs</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>ISP</th>
            <th>ASN</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className="data">
          {hosts.map(host => (
            <tr key={host.name}>
              <td>{host.name}</td>
              <td>
                {host.ip_addresses.map((ip: any) => (
                  <div key={ip.ip}>{ip.ip}</div>
                ))}
              </td>
              <td>
                {host.ip_addresses.map((ip: any) => (
                  <div key={ip.reverse_dns}>{ip.reverse_dns}</div>
                ))}
              </td>

              <td>{host.ip_addresses[0].location.country_code}</td>
              <td>{host.ip_addresses[0].isp}</td>
              <td>{host.ip_addresses[0].asn}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResultTableNew;
```

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "name": "library.example.com",
        "ip_addresses": [
            {
                "ip": "10.0.0.10",
                "reverse_dns": "library.example.com.",
                "location": {
                    "city": "Charlottesville",
                    "region_code": "VA",
                    "region_name": "Virginia",
                    "country_code": "US",
                    "country_name": "United States",
                    "continent_code": "NA",
                    "continent_name": "North America",
                    "latitude": 38.0370483398438,
                    "longitude": -78.517951965332
                },
                "isp": "Amazon, Inc.",
                "asn": 225
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "arts.example.com",
        "ip_addresses": [
            {
                "ip": "10.0.0.2",
                "reverse_dns": null,
                "location": {
                    "city": "Manhattan",
                    "region_code": "NY",
                    "region_name": "New York",
                    "country_code": "US",
                    "country_name": "United States",
                    "continent_code": "NA",
                    "continent_name": "North America",
                    "latitude": 40.7589111328125,
                    "longitude": -73.9790191650391
                },
                "isp": "Digitalocean LLC",
                "asn": 14061
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Is this your all data?, I think one of your data location is null. that is the problem.

Comment: @Jagan yes you are right...i truncated the data for posting purposes but found an entry where location was null.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use lodash

```
npm i --save lodash
```

You can import it as

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

And in your code

```
return (
<div>
  <Table variant="dark" responsive striped hover>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Hostname</th>
        <th>IPs</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>ISP</th>
        <th>ASN</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody className="data">
      {hosts.map(host => (
        <tr key={host.name}>
          <td>{host.name}</td>
          <td>
            {host.ip_addresses.map((ip: any) => (
              <div key={ip.ip}>{ip.ip}</div>
            ))}
          </td>
          <td>
            {host.ip_addresses.map((ip: any) => (
              <div key={ip.reverse_dns}>{ip.reverse_dns}</div>
            ))}
          </td>

          <td>{_.get(host, "ip_addresses[0].location.country_code", "")}</td>
          <td>{host.ip_addresses[0].isp}</td>
          <td>{host.ip_addresses[0].asn}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </Table>
</div>
);
};
```

This way it will never throw an exception, You can also a give a default value in the third parameter of _.get function.